# http basic auth with swashbuckle api documentation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

could anyone know how could i integrate basic auth with swashbuckle api's documentation?

I saw that there's a basicAuth function in the swaggerconfig file:

```
    c.BasicAuth("basic").Description("Basic HTTP Authentication");
```

What i've done:

- uncommented the previous line but nothing changed!

does anyone have any idea what did i miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how i did httpbasic authentication:

```cs
public class AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter: IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var filterPipeline = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
        var isAuthorized = filterPipeline
                                         .Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
                                         .Any(filter => filter is IAuthorizationFilter);

        var allowAnonymous = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();

        if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
        {
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter {
                name = "Authorization",
                @in = "header",
                description = "access token",
                required = true,
                type = "string"                    
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The api's user shall write in the field value: basic [un:pw].tobase64.

References:
[swashbuckle's issue 326](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/326)
[swashbuckle issue 2](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/290)

Comment: Getting error for System.Web.Http 4.0.0 not able to load. Using framework 4.6.1.

Any help

Answer (score 8):

A minor improvement on @MarwaAhmad 's most excellent answer, is to check for null parameters (e.g. a simple GET or call with all params in the URL) . Also added details for Basic Auth.

Also, if you already use a global `IAuthorizationFilter` for say enforcing HTTPS, then you will want to change the more general

```cs
filter => filter is IAuthorizationFilter
```

to a specific

```cs
filter => filter is AuthorizeAttribute
```

```cs
    public class AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            var filterPipeline = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
            var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
                .Any(filter => filter is IAuthorizationFilter);

            var allowAnonymous =
                apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();

            if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
            {
                if (operation.parameters == null)
                    operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

                operation.parameters?.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    name = "Authorization",
                    @in = "header",
                    description = "Basic HTTP Base64 encoded Header Authorization",
                    required = true,
                    type = "string"
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting error for System.Web.Http 4.0.0 not able to load. Using framework 4.6.1. Any help