# .NET MVC Swashbuckle gated by Basic Auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Is there a way to gate SwashBuckle documentation page behind a Basic Auth attribute? So only those with the right username and password can see the documentation page.

The swashbuckle is configured with

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger
```

and

```
.EnableSwaggerUi
```

but it creates its own MessageHandler so there is no where for me to attach my Basic Auth attribute which is implemented as a `ActionFilterAttribute`.

I also do not want the basic auth to be applied to the entire site, just the swagger endpoints

Answer (score 4):

If i got it correctly, then your case might be similar to this ([image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6348433/7586420/0dbeb29a-f8ad-11e4-94c9-3ef8ba1f4d90.png)) also this ([image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6348433/7637614/8658d834-fa6f-11e4-8667-1b865a645d9f.png)).
Here's what i have done & worked:

```html
 public class AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter: IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var filterPipeline = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
        var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance).Any(filter => filter is IAuthorizationFilter);

        var allowAnonymous = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
        var basicAuthenticator = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<MyBasicAuthenticator>().Any();            
        
        //because the attribute might be at controller or action method            
        var myTokenAuthenticator = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<MyTokenAuthenticator>().Any(); 
  
        //actionname: certain controllers
        if (isAuthorized != null)
        {
            if (operation != null)
            {
                if (operation.parameters == null)
                {
                    operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
                }
                if (myTokenAuthenticator)
                {                       
                    operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter()
                    {
                        name = "Authorization",
                        @in = "header",
                        description = "Id obtained from the service method authenticate. Ex: MyToken ID",
                        required = true,
                        type = "string"                            
                    });
                }
                if (basicAuthenticator)
                {
                    operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter()
                    {
                        name = "Authorization",
                        @in = "header",
                        type = "string",                              
                        description = "basic http authentication. Ex: Basic (Email:Password).ToBase64",
                        @required = true
                    });                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similar issues:
[swashbuckle q.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222117/http-basic-auth-with-swashbuckle-api-documentation)

Comment: you may replace 'MyBasicAuthenticator' and 'MyTokenAuthenticator' with your custom attribute.

Comment: sadly that's not what i was looking for. This is to allow you to make documented requests that are basic authed. What i was looking for was a basic auth to SEE the doc page.

Comment: An answer was to use DelegatingHandler, to a Q similar to yours [I cant find any info on how to restrict access to swagger documentation. Can anyone help?](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/334)

Here's [how to implement DelegatingHandler](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/implementing-message-handlers-to-track-your-asp-net-web-api-usage/) .Hope these might help.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to solve this issue, and not finding answer found what wanted.

repeating the question: How to restrict the swagger ui page with authentication, which ever you choose, require login and such.

Answer: Web.config location authorization

add following location to your web.config (change swagger if have different base path setup)

```
<configuration>
  <location path="swagger">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="api"/> 

        <deny users="*"/> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

above allows users with 'api' role and restricts everyone else.

Falls back to authorization model for what to do when denied. In my case user redirected to login page.